# Status Bar and navigation title and items appear a bit later after presenting Navigation controller from App delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

```
let check = defaults.bool(forKey: "logged_in")
    if(check){
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homevc") a[enter image description here][1]s! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

[here is when rootviewcontroller is visible and after few seconds firstly status bar appears magically and than navigation bar attributes appears.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0):

UI changes has to be made on main thread. Make sure that the window.makeKeyAndVisible() function is called on the main thread. Like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: tried it but its not working at all still blank navigation at presenting time after 2-3 seconds all the stuff appears :/